# The table in the database (SQLite) is not created in the oncreate method

Tags: android-sqlite

I am developing a mobile application in Android Studio. I have a "BreakfastDatabaseHelper" class for an SQLite database. Initially, I created the "breakfast" and "calories_summary" tables and methods for them there.

```
package com.example.calorieapp.ui.dashboard;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class BreakfastDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "breakfast_database";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    static final String TABLE_BREAKFAST = "breakfast";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_GRAMS = "grams";
    public static final String COLUMN_CALORIES = "calories";
    public static final String COLUMN_PROTEIN = "protein";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAT = "fat";
    public static final String COLUMN_CARBOHYDRATE = "carbohydrate";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";

    // SQL query to create the breakfast table
    private static final String CREATE_BREAKFAST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BREAKFAST + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_GRAMS + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_CALORIES + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_PROTEIN + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_FAT + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_CARBOHYDRATE + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT);";


    static final String TABLE_CALORIES_SUMMARY = "calories_summary";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY = "date_summary";
    public static final String COLUMN_TOTAL_CALORIES = "total_calories";

    // SQL query to create the calories_summary table
    // SQL query to create the calories_summary table
    private static final String CREATE_CALORIES_SUMMARY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CALORIES_SUMMARY + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_TOTAL_CALORIES + " REAL);";

    static final String TABLE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY = "protein_summary";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY_PROTEIN = "date_summary_protein";
    public static final String COLUMN_TOTAL_PROTEIN = "total_protein";

    // SQL query to create the calories_summary table
    // SQL query to create the calories_summary table

    private static final String CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY_PROTEIN + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_TOTAL_PROTEIN + " REAL);";


    public BreakfastDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BREAKFAST_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CALORIES_SUMMARY_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE);

        Log.d("BreakfastDatabaseHelper", "Tables created: breakfast, calories_summary");
    }


    public void updateCaloriesSummary(String date) {
        // Выполняем запрос для получения суммы калорий по выбранной дате с округлением до сотых
        String query = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(" + COLUMN_CALORIES + "), 2) FROM " + TABLE_BREAKFAST +
                " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + " = ?";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{date});

        double totalCalories = 0;

        // Если есть результат, переходим к первой записи
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            totalCalories = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }

        cursor.close();

        // Теперь вставляем или обновляем данные в таблице calories_summary
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY, date);
        values.put(COLUMN_TOTAL_CALORIES, totalCalories);

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.replace(TABLE_CALORIES_SUMMARY, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    public double getTotalCaloriesSummary(String date) {
        // Выполняем запрос для получения суммы калорий из таблицы calories_summary по выбранной дате
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_TOTAL_CALORIES + " FROM " + TABLE_CALORIES_SUMMARY +
                " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY + " = ?" +
                " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC";  // Упорядочиваем по убыванию id

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{date});

        double totalCalories = 0;

        // Если есть результат, переходим к первой записи
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            totalCalories = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return totalCalories;
    }



    public void updateProteinSummary(String date) {
        // Выполняем запрос для получения суммы калорий по выбранной дате с округлением до сотых
        String query = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(" + COLUMN_PROTEIN + "), 2) FROM " + TABLE_BREAKFAST +
                " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + " = ?";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{date});

        double totalProtein = 0;

        // Если есть результат, переходим к первой записи
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            totalProtein = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }

        cursor.close();

        // Теперь вставляем или обновляем данные в таблице protein_summary
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY_PROTEIN, date);
        values.put(COLUMN_TOTAL_PROTEIN, totalProtein);

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.replace(TABLE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    public double getTotalProteinSummary(String date) {
        // Выполняем запрос для получения суммы калорий из таблицы protein_summary по выбранной дате
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_TOTAL_PROTEIN + " FROM " + TABLE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY +
                " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE_SUMMARY_PROTEIN + " = ?" +
                " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC";  // Упорядочиваем по убыванию id

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{date});

        double totalProtein = 0;

        // Если есть результат, переходим к первой записи
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            totalProtein = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return totalProtein;
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d("BreakfastDatabaseHelper", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        // Handle database upgrades if needed
    }

}
```

Now I want to create a table "protein_summary". I do it by analogy "calories_summary", add the line db.execSQL(CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE) to the onCreate method, but the table is not created. What could this be related to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onCreate` method is only called when the database does not exist. The typical way to amend the schema is to utilise the `onUpgrade` method. The `onUpgrade` method is called/invoked when the version number is increased.

- this is a common misconception as an activity's `onCreate` method appears to always be called, but as a database persists then it is only created the once for the App (unless deleted). Underlying is a file, if the file exists then the database exists.

So you need to increase the version number `DATABASE_VERSION` (typically by increasing it by 1) and then have the onUpgrade method create the table noting that you should cater for the respective upgrade by testing the `oldVersion` and `newVersion`.

You should also update the `onCreate` to also create the amended schema so that a new installation creates the correct schema for the version.

If you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....` rather than `CREATE TABLE ....` then you can have the `onUpgrade` call the `onCreate` and so only the missing table(s) get created.

As a **Demonstration** based upon the code in the question.

Consider the following changes

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

- changed from 2 to 1 (not sure if you would jump to 3 from 2)

and:-

```
private static final String CREATE_BREAKFAST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ....
private static final String CREATE_CALORIES_SUMMARY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ....
private static final String CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ....
```

And JUST FOR EASE of the DEMO:-

```
if (DATABASE_VERSION > 1) db.execSQL(CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE);
```

- instead of just `db.execSQL(CREATE_PROTEIN_SUMMARY_TABLE);`

And lastly:-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.d("BreakfastDatabaseHelper", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    // Handle database upgrades if needed
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Now with the following Activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BreakfastDatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new BreakfastDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("DBVERSION","Database version is " + db.getVersion());
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master",null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

The the log shows:-

```
2024-03-23 12:41:58.636 D/BreakfastDatabaseHelper: Tables created: breakfast, calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:41:58.638 D/DBVERSION: Database version is 1
2024-03-23 12:41:58.638 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@8962cfb
2024-03-23 12:41:58.639 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    name=breakfast
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    tbl_name=breakfast
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE breakfast (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_name TEXT, grams REAL, calories REAL, protein REAL, fat REAL, carbohydrate REAL, date TEXT)
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:41:58.640 I/System.out: 2 {
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out: 3 {
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    name=calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    tbl_name=calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE calories_summary (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_summary TEXT, total_calories REAL)
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:41:58.641 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. just the original 2 tables

With just the single change:-

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

And the App rerun, then the log:-

```
2024-03-23 12:55:42.359 D/BreakfastDatabaseHelper: Upgrading database from version 1 to 2
2024-03-23 12:55:42.360 D/BreakfastDatabaseHelper: Tables created: breakfast, calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:55:42.362 D/DBVERSION: Database version is 2
2024-03-23 12:55:42.362 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@8962cfb
2024-03-23 12:55:42.363 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-03-23 12:55:42.363 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-03-23 12:55:42.364 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    name=breakfast
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    tbl_name=breakfast
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE breakfast (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_name TEXT, grams REAL, calories REAL, protein REAL, fat REAL, carbohydrate REAL, date TEXT)
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out: 2 {
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2024-03-23 12:55:42.365 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out: 3 {
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    name=calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    tbl_name=calories_summary
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE calories_summary (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_summary TEXT, total_calories REAL)
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out: 4 {
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    name=protein_summary
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    tbl_name=protein_summary
2024-03-23 12:55:42.366 I/System.out:    rootpage=7
2024-03-23 12:55:42.367 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE protein_summary (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_summary_protein TEXT, total_protein REAL)
2024-03-23 12:55:42.367 I/System.out: }
2024-03-23 12:55:42.367 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. the 3 tables now exist.

- if any data existed in the original 2 tables then that would be retained as the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....` for the 2 original tables would be noops as the tables exist.

Perhaps note the very first line, output according to your original code from the `onUpgrade` method.

Also note that accidentally (on purpose) the logged output from `onCreate` was not changed to reflect the new table. Thus the benefit of actually ascertaining what is via the query on sqlite_master (the database's schema).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation! Everything worked out!